# Raleway font not working in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

I want to edit the text and font of [this .psd file](http://dougkeeling.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Supertext-KDM.psd), which is part of a tutorial [here](http://dougkeeling.com/tutorials/tutorial-supertext/). I installed the Raleway fonts, which are also available on that website. Then, I opened the `.psd` file with Photoshop, but it gives the following message (in Spanish, I'm sorry):

[image]

which is something like:

> *Some text layers contain fonts that are not available. You will have to substitute them before they can be used for vector-something...*

When I select Edit -> Find and replace... it says something like:

> *Text layer "Superman (Font:Raleway)" is hidden and cannot be searched...*

This can also be seen in the layers' menu:

[image]

However, I can create text boxes with Raleway fonts, including the ExtraBold, which is supposed to be the one used here:

[image]

Finally, if I attempt to save as `.pdf`, I get something like:

> _ The following fonts cannot be found in the text layer "Superman (Font:Raleway)":
>
> Raleway Heavy
>
> That layer cannot be included...

Yet, that font does not exist! What is the problem?

PS: first time using PS. Hopefully this is not a supernoob issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you downloaded the fonts from a different place than whoever supplied the PSD. There could be some difference in the font file that makes your computer think it isn't the same font. Allow Photoshop to replace it with something similar then highlight the font you want and change it to the Raleway you have. If that doesn't work you could just delete that layer with the missing font and remake whatever was in it.

Comment: Correct. However, the problem is that the link from the website does not include the heavy version, which is available from another site: [here](http://www.1001fonts.com/raleway-font.html).